# Scroll parent element to position of neighbouring component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of **Items**:

```
const items = [{id: 1, linked_id: 5}, {id: 2, linked_id: 1}, {id: 3, linked_id: 5}, {id: 4, linked_id: 1}, {id: 5, linked_id: 1}];
```

Im rendering it like this:

```
<div style="max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
  <ul>
    {items.map((item) => <Item key={item.id} {...item}/>)}
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the **Item** component looks like this:

```
const Item = ({id, linked_id}) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
     // ???
  }

  return (<li>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>[Scroll to: {linked_id}]</button>
  </li>)
}
```

When i click button inside **Item**, i need parent div (the one with overflow: auto) to scroll to linked **Item**. How to i solve it cleanly? Do i need to forward parent div reference to every Item and then make checks inside every **Item**? Seems excessive

Comment: You can add a `id` selector to your component and with javascript you can do something like this `document.getElementById(id)?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" })`